# How to measure coverage when running typescript tests using karma and bazel?

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, bazel

I'm converting a karma+webpack test runner for typescript to use Bazel. The current system reports code coverage using karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter.  How should I measure coverage when running typescript tests with karma using Bazel?

I tried adding the karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter and karma-coverage-istanbul-instrumenter plugins to a karma config file and using that with karma_web_test_suite.

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    reporters: ['coverage-istanbul'],
    preprocessors: {
      "**/!(*.spec).js": ["karma-coverage-istanbul-instrumenter"]
    },
    coverageIstanbulInstrumenter: {
      esModules: false,
      produceSourceMap: true
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['text-summary', 'html'],
      dir: path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, "coverage")
    }
  })
};
```

```py
# BUILD.bazel
karma_web_test_suite(
    name = "test",
    config_file = "//:karma.conf.js",
    data = [":ts_src"],
    deps = [
        ":test_lib",
    ],
)
```

Superficially this works, the code is instrumented by istanbul and it reports coverage in the text summary to stdout.  However, there are a couple of issues with the html reporter, which tries to read the typescript source files from the js sourcemaps.

1. Is there a way to get the transitive closure of all the source files from the :test_lib ts_library?  In the example above, it works around this by providing a data attribute to the karma web test that references a filegroup (ts_src) but this becomes hard to manage if there is a nested dependency graph of ts_libraries.
2. The paths to the source files in the sourcemaps are no longer correct when the source files are used from the karma TESTSRC_DIR.

I could write a karma preprocessor to manipulate the sourcemaps paths but it feels like there should be a better way of doing this?

Comment: were you able to find a good way for fixing the paths in the source maps?